# cant't figure out how to fix the error ''An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.''

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, syntax, rdd

How to fix this error when I write the mapping function in pyspark. The error I get is (Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.)

```
def user_rep(x):
       acc = str(x[x.find('" Id="')+6:x.find('" LastAccessDate=')].encode('utf-8'))
    
    if x.find('Reputation="')==-1:
        return [acc,0]
    else:
        rep = int(x[x.find('Reputation="')+12:x.find('" UpVotes=')])
        return [acc,rep]
lines_user = sc.textFile(localpath('/spark-stats-data/allUsers/'))
rows_user=lines_user.filter(lambda x: isrow(x)) 
reputation = rows_user.map(user_rep)
reputation.count()

reputation_user = reputation.map(lambda acc,rep:(rep,acc)).sortByKey(ascending=False)
```

Comment: When you say that you're getting an error, the very next thing you should do is include the **exact, complete error message**. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. Please [edit] your post to add that information.

Comment: Can you post the entire error message? Additionally, I would strongly recommend you to explain your use case along with the sample input and expected output.

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 62)